# Android: Progress Dialog Not Displaying

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have a main activity that launches a child activity using the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName(MyChildActivity.class.getPackage().getName(), MyChildActivity.class.getName());
((Activity)context).startActivity(intent);
```

I am trying to perform a time-consuming task in the child activity and would like to display a ProgressDialog while I do so. My code looks like this:

```
private ProgressDialog _progressDialog;

private OnClickListener btn_onClick = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        _progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
            v.getContext(),
            "Please wait",
            "Performing task..."
        );

        TaskThread t = new ExportThread(v.getContext());
        t.start();
    }
};

private class TaskThread extends Thread{
    private Context _context;

    public TaskThread(Context context) {
        _context = context;
    }

    private Handler _handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            _progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    };


    @Override
    public void run() {
        performTask(_context);
        _handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
}
```

For some reason, the ProgressDialog is not displaying. If I use that same code in the main activity, it works - but not in the child activity. In addition, the following code also fails to display the ProgressDialog (but the Toast does display):

```
private ProgressDialog _progressDialog;

private OnClickListener _btn_onClick = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        _progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
            v.getContext(),
            "Please wait",
            "Performing task..."
        );

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        _progressDialog.dismiss();

        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Done with progress dialog.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

Any ideas out there? Are we not allowed to display a ProgressDialog from a child activity?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why use thread instead of [async task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)?

Async task implements the method **onProgressUpdate** and **publishProgress** which makes it easy to display and update UI/progress dialogs.

Here is some example code: http://android-projects.de/2010/12/08/threading-in-android-apps-wir-entwickeln-einen-zahler/

Comment: Thanks, ArtWorkAD. I have no idea why your suggestion worked, but it did. Could you explain to me why the AsyncTask approach worked when the Thread approach did not? Thank you.

Comment: well is your thread working? how does it access and update UI? as you can see your code is very complicated and using native thread class it is a hard job to set an app up and running. normally apps have a lot of threads, maybe up to 40. How to you organize them. With your approach it is almost impossible to manage the threads. so try to use async-task, it helps you a lot!

Comment: In the Thread approach, all the code is executed just fine. The task is performed. However, the ProgressDialog does not ever appear. When using the AsyncTask approach, though, the ProgressDialog appears. That's the part I don't understand.