# Cannot get ProgressDialog to stop after WebView has loaded

Tags: java, android, webview, refresh, progressdialog

I can get the ProgressDialog to show, but I cannot get it to stop after the WebView has been loaded.  All I need is a simple refresh button for it.

Here is the working code so far:

```
      public class Quotes extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

      WebView webview;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);
      webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      webview.loadUrl("http://www.dgdevelco.com/quotes/quotesandroid.html");

      View refreshClick = findViewById(R.id.refresh);
      refreshClick.setOnClickListener(this);

      }


      public void onClick(View v){
           switch(v.getId()){

           case R.id.refresh:
                ProgressDialog.show(Quotes.this, "", "Loading...", true);
                webview.reload();

                }
           }
      }
```

I just can't figure it out. I've looked everywhere but nothing seems to work.

Comment: From the related section to the right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017375/android-showing-a-progress-dialog http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283819/how-do-i-make-my-progress-dialog-dismiss-after-webview-is-loaded http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388142/how-do-i-show-and-then-remove-an-android-progress-dialog http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395411/android-progress-dialog-not-displaying There are many, many more...

Comment: There is a outline of a Tick under the numbers to the left of the answer. Press that. It is how you mark an answer correct and get's you on the road of addiction to StackOverflow ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right this is the quick answer, you should really implement your own class for the WebViewClient, you should show the dialog in that class as well but you'll figure that out.

First, make your dialog global, (in your real app you might want to pass it in to your client, or declare it in the webviewclient, then override on onPageStarted as well).

```
  ProgressDialog dialog;
```

then simply:

```
 webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });



   public void onClick(View v){
       switch(v.getId()){

       case R.id.refresh:
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Quotes.this, "", "Loading...", true);
            webview.reload();

            }
       }
  }
```

This is the API you need: [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html)

*EDIT*

Ok it was annoying me, here is the proper way:

```
 public class Quotes extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

  private WebView webview;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(this));
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.dgdevelco.com/quotes/quotesandroid.html");

    findViewById(R.id.refresh).setOnClickListener(this);
  }


  public void onClick(View v){
       switch(v.getId()){
       case R.id.refresh:
            webview.reload();
             break;
            }
       }
  }
```

The new class:

```
 public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    private Context mContext;
    private ProgressDialog mDialog;

  public MyWebViewClient(Context context){
    mContext = context;
  }

  @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            mDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "", "Loading...", true);
        }

    @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            mDialog.dismiss();
        }

 }
```

Comment: IT WORKED!!!  YOU SOOOOO ROCK!!!  Thank you soooooo soooooo much!  I knew it had to be there somewhere.  You So Rock!  thank you  thank you  thank you.  :)